# Is my Sword Coast resident likely to have seen a dinosaur?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, forgotten-realms

I am playing a druid and am wondering whether my character has seen dinosaurs. My character has lived most of his life on the Sword Coast.

Does the Sword Coast have dinosaurs, or are they from a foreign land? I am specifically interested Quetzalcoatlus by the way.

I'll also add that this character in question is level 8 and has had a bit of a life and been through war etc, but has not really traveled extensively far from home.

Comment: Are you looking for lore/info from 5e specifically, or is material from previous editions fine as well?

Comment: What level are you?

Comment: @ NautArch Level 8 now

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Your Sword Coast druid probably hasn't seen a dino

*Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* doesn't mention dinosaurs at all. That's not decisive as it's not an exhaustive setting book, but it is the closest thing to a "pure" setting book for the Realms that's been published so far for *5e*.

*Xanathar's Guide to Everything* gives some hints as to where druids might see dinosaurs: the plesiosaurus appears on the Coast and Underwater tables; the pteranodon, allosaurus, anklyosaurus, and triceratops on the Grassland table; pteranodon on the Mountain table.  So maybe you've seen a plesiosaurus on a 4th-grade whale-watching trip, or a menagerie traveling up from Calimshan had an allosaurus with it? (The Coastal Encounters tables include pteranodons and plesiosaurus later in that book. Grassland Encounters include anklyosaurus, allosaurus, pteranodons, triceratops, and even tyrannosaurus rex.)

However, there's nothing in *5e*'s literature of the Sword Coast (*SCAG*, *Tyranny of Dragons*, *Princes of the Apocalypse*, *Storm King's Thunder*, and other adventures) to suggest that dinosaurs are native to that part of Faerûn.

### Hop a boat south, though…

…And you'll arrive in Chult, and Chult is *teeming* with dinosaurs. You can't spit without hitting one! Really, just take a look at this *Tomb of Annihilation* [promotional piece](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/tomb-annihilation) that depicts Chult's Port Nyanzaru:

[image: Port Nyanzaru]
Dinos everywhere!

Comment: I am interested in Quetzalcoatlus if that makes any difference. I would have hoped they would fly all over :)